# Invalid Certificate on *.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl

When trying to browse https://stackoverflow.com I receive an error that the certificate is not valid. The reason is that *.stackoverflow.com comes with a certificate for *.stackexchange.com at the moment.

[image]

More details:

SHA-1 fingerprint of the cert:

> DD:BE:B5:C8:5C:F8:40:66:23:AE:1D:93:6B:FE:91:7D:B6:59:CA:54

Issued by: DigiCert High Assurance CA-3

Comment: Same problem: tried to reach stackoverflow.com but the server name is *.stackexchange.com on Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m, Windows Seven Enterprise

Comment: Well, they are in the process of re-issuing certificates after fixing a [critical bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228777/152859), guess this will go away by itself when the process will be done. :)

Comment: QUICK EVERYBODY EXPLOIT TH— oh.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a race condition as we upgraded certs immediately but DNS took a bit to catch up. You should now be seeing a valid cert which we'll be updating again as soon as we receive a new combined wildcard for that particular certificate.

Most CAs are a bit busy today which is understandable.

Comment: Why are they particularly busy today?

Comment: @Duncan In case that wasn't sarcasm here is a link to the [reason CAs are busy today](http://www.zdnet.com/heartbleed-serious-openssl-zero-day-vulnerability-revealed-7000028166/).

Comment: @MatthewGreen It wasn't sarcasm, thanks for the link.

Comment: What about [per-site-metas](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aEuwL.png)? I see the same warning when opening any of them directly using HTTPS.

Comment: @AsheeshR we do not support SSL on per-site metas and won't at their current URLs at all. Note: we don't link you to them over `https://` either.

Comment: The "sign in" link does point to `https://`

Comment: @ThiefMaster The "sign in" link doesn't point to the child meta. It would (appropriately) throw an invalid cert warning in almost every browser if it did.

Comment: I went to http://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/ and clicked "sign up" (sorry, not "sign in"). I ended up in https://meta.arduino.stackexchange.com/users/signup?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2fmeta.arduino.stackexchange.com%2f which does not have a valid certificate.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's *definitely* a bug, it'll be fixed in the next build.