# Should Stack Exchange log out all users from the network and let them sign in again in the wake of the Heartbleed vulnerability?

Tags: discussion, security

I see that over the past few days the hype for "Heartbleed Security Vulnerability" has increased. Several sites administrators have take actions to prevent their servers from being compromised.

Stack Exchange has also taken few steps to protect its users' data. Some of the methods have been mentioned here

[Is Stack Exchange safe from Heartbleed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228758/is-stack-exchange-safe-from-heartbleed)

**Isn't it a good idea to logout all users from the network and let them signin again so that all the keys have been updated?**

SoundCloud is doing this and I guess StackOverFlow and other Stack Exchange sites should take this into consideration. It can help.

Comment: [This might be relevant?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228758/is-stack-exchange-safe-from-heartbleed?lq=1#comment750472_228777)

Comment: "Several sites administrators have take actions to prevent their servers from being compromised." I really hope tens of thousands have.

Comment: Is it a good idea to log users out and let them login again? Is it a good move?

Comment: @djechlin Ehhh... as long as a handful of them have. How many sites can really be out there, anyway? ;-)

Comment: @AndrewBarber You're assuming one admin per site.  Apparently those few admins simply administrate all however many billion sites out there.  It can't be *that* much work, after all.

Comment: This action might give users a sense of security that steps are being taken to protect their data.

Comment: @TalhaMasood A sense, perhaps. But I think the reality is more important.

Comment: @Servy Actually, I was assuming that handful of admins was managing Facebook, Twitter, and Stack Overflow. Are you saying there are other sites out there??

Comment: @Servy if you want to think about it further, also don't assume one site per terminator - many sites are served behind shared terminators, even here.

Comment: @AndrewBarber And what is that reality? Are we really safe. Is their a possibility that one fine morning I wake up to see that my account at Stack Exchange has been compromised.

Comment: I just noticed my account has been compromised as early as 2009, and the hackers have been spouting nothing but nonsense in my name. I am shocked and demand urgent action

Comment: @Pëkka Right away. I'll suspend your account in the interim!

Comment: I have the name of a good shrink, @Pëkka

Comment: I might be naive as to what the impact is, but what's wrong with leaving up to the individual users?  If their account gets compromised because they failed to take the necessary steps, is that really SE's problem?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Excellent :) That's what I wanted to hear

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, odds are the vast majority of users aren't aware that there is a risk; many might be willing to act if they knew there was a problem requiring an action.

Comment: @Servy this means SO should educate users about this next time they login. People need to know that there is a problem and SO won't let anyone steal it's users' info.

Comment: @TalhaMasood - You **are** aware that none of the Q&A sites hold passwords, right?

Comment: @TalhaMasood Meh, easier to just silently fix the problem, if possible/needed, rather than getting people worked up over something that has already been resolved.  It's probably *more* work to educate them to the point of being able to solve the problem than it is to just solve it for them.

Comment: @Oded I login to SO using my Google Account. I think they do save the security Token against that.

Comment: @AndrewBarber well, there's about 150k serverfault users, so there's that.

Comment: @servy "The greatest object in educating is to give a right habit" -Maria Mitchell

Comment: @Oded Wait, you mean that gmail password renewal request email I got from administrator@stac.koverflow.com was fake??