# Heartbleed and logged in persistence

Tags: discussion, heartbleed

As Stack Overflow was one of the sites affected by [Heartbleed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed_bug), and [it is fixed now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228758/is-stack-exchange-safe-from-heartbleed):

How is it possible that after re-issuing certificates, my account is still logged in? It must be invalidated and log me out.

As mentioned in this [post](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/55087):

Heartbleed means:

- Invalidating all session keys and cookies

Am I missing something? Or are my cookies not getting invalidated?

Comment: Read starting from [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228758/is-stack-exchange-safe-from-heartbleed?lq=1#comment750462_228777)

Comment: What OpenID provider are you using? And SSL certificates != login session.

Comment: Keep in mind that if SO invalidated your login session, but your openID provider didn't, then SO would ask your openID provider to authenticate and it could be doing so based on a cached session.  This makes you appear to stay logged in, as a user, even though you logged out and back in from SE's perspective.

Comment: I think they were only vulnerable on the blog site; all SE sites run on windows servers which don't use OpenSSL.

Comment: @Won't the SSL terminates at haproxy, which was vulnerable. It did affect all the sites. That's why they reissued all the certificates.