# 2FA for Stack Exchange universal login

Tags: feature-request, login

I'm aware there's already [a FR for this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256767/332043), but it applied to OpenID. With [OpenID now being deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/332043), that feature request will never be implemented. Therefore, this feature request for 2FA asks specifically about the universal login system that still exists. The current system still supports email/password login without using a third-party SSO system, but there's no 2FA.

Is there any chance a 2FA system could be implemented?

Comment: At this time, not really. The system hasn't actually changed all that much since that discussion, and pretty much all the same points and discussions stand. Most users aren't all that interested in having us implement this, so it will likely remain in the back seat to focus on more important things.

Comment: From my duplicate question: "I was somewhat surprised to see that StackExchange currently doesn't seem to offer anything beyond a simple password. Not hugely surprised, mind you, as there's nothing of any material worth that's secured (unlike, for example, an email account).

On the other hand, some people spend a lot of time on the site and have garnered reputations (both in the old-fashioned sense, and the imaginary points) that they might want to protect. Plus, I imagine some people have correspondence that may be sensitive in Stackoverflow Jobs, which uses the same credentials."

Comment: In other words, a big plus-one from this user!

Comment: "there's nothing of any material worth that's secured" – as a moderator on two sites, I strongly disagree. If someone would obtain a moderator's credentials, a lot of damage could be done. Which is why I don't understand why, after several years since this was brought up first, it still is "At this time, not really" @animuson. And no, using a Google or Facebook account is no option for me, I value my privacy and don't trust those two (especially not the latter). Currently I often have to put additional load on my co-mods shoulders because of that when I'm not at my own machine.