# Will you reconsider adding 2FA? For example, FIDO2 or TOTP codes?

Tags: feature-request, login, user-accounts

I'm actually shocked to find that such a large site does not have [2FA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication). I saw mention of telling people to just rely on the 2FA of other sites such as Google or GitHub when signing in, but that short-sightedness is obvious once one tries to log in to a non-Stack Overflow site when they don't use email and password.

It would be nice to be able to use an authenticator client such as [Bitwarden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwarden) or use a [YubiKey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YubiKey) ([FIDO2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDO_Alliance#FIDO2)) in order to be able to sign in, or at the very least, make it so a password is not the only thing preventing an unauthorized sign in (the distinction is specific for FIDO2 as FIDO2 both allows passwordless login and acting as a secondary security layer depending on what the user decides if both are implemented in a site).

I would like to request for you to reconsider this and implement [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password) and FIDO2 for authentication.

---

I don't believe a duplicate closure against [Two-factor authentication for Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230490/two-factor-authentication-for-stack-exchange) is warranted because this request deserves a second chance:

8 to 9 years have passed since the original request and [its related one about OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256767), which is a *long* time in computer security. I also feel that the reasoning I've outlined above addresses the rationale given by the company for the original decline, which should be enough to warrant this new, "duplicate" request.

Comment: The duplicate target question is outdated. SE stopped using OpenID five years ago, so the context is different.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It's still relevant today. The "Stack Exchange OpenID" mentioned there was SE's email/password authentication, just handled through a complicated OpenID code path, and which was migrated to a simpler path when OpenID support ended.

Comment: @Sonic which essentially means, AFAIK, that is can no longer be used elsewhere as OpenID provider as few users used to do. (Not nearly enough to justify keeping the support.)

Comment: Anyway as for the feature request, those who want more security can just use Google or Facebook.

Comment: @ShadowWizardIsSadAndAngry Those who want more security should give up all their privacy? That’s not a very helpful suggestion.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek and who says Stack Exchange keeps our privacy any better? On the contrary, if you ask me, and now with all the recent events, more than ever - my trust in them is below zero. I trust Google much more. (Not FB, but that's not the issue)

Comment: the question is still very relevant today and the original reasons for not implementing the feature in the past were invalid due to the aforementioned reasons listed in the question. y'all can vote to re-open the question if y'all want as even though it is "technically a duplicate", but the nature of the question and the 8 year time gap overrides the old question. this feature does need to be implemented though as StackExchange is falling behind in authentication practices and for a dev oriented site, it's a bit baffling to see it so far behind

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because the duplicate is _nine and a half_ years old, and [no compelling reasons were given by the company for the decline](/a/257239), even back then. The [linked question](/q/256767) provides little to no apparent explanation, despite being linked under that pretense. The only actual reasoning I can find is [a concern that adoption would be low](/posts/comments/945069), which is 1) wildly unsatisfying as an answer, because security shouldn't depend on adoption, and 2) based on old data at this point, given that the OpenID request was canned _eight_ and a half years ago.

Comment: This deserves a modern re-look by the company, even if the choice is still to decline.

Comment: @Alexis I summarized [your above comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1318848) into your post as reopen rationale; feel free to edit or remove if you don't feel it's accurate or to your liking.

Comment: I've voted to reopen now that this satisfies the [guidelines for reconsideration requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago).

Comment: I think that in particular, the fact that mods have access to PII is enough to warrant adding 2FA/MFA as an option, at least for mods (and possibly as a requirement for mods?). For regular users, it might just be a matter of securing their accounts, but for mods, it's a matter of ensuring *everyone's* PII is secure.

Comment: @V2Blast or require mods to use Google or Facebook, though guess that won't be accepted very well.